# Setting spring config in Ant target

Tags: java, spring, ant, javabeans, target

I am new to Ant and the Spring Framework. Is it possible to define the `spring-config` file to be used by various Java classes within an Ant target? I am asking because I want to create two separate targets that take different beans.

Answer (score 0):

You can have many web.xml files, and config spring-confic files in each web.xml file correspondly. And in ant build.xml for each target you can specified different web.xml file.

In web.xml

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/app-ontrollers.xml
        /WEB-INF/app-service.xml
        /WEB-INF/app-data.xml
        /WEB-INF/app-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

In build.xml

```
<property name="web.xml" value="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml" />

<target name="release" depends="compile">
    <war warfile="${dist}/${web.app.name}" webxml="${web.xml}">
        ...
    </war>
        ...
</target>
```